# Need help proving an analogue of the Weierstrauss M-Test for Improper Integrals:

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

If $f(x,t)$ satisfies $|f(x,t)| < g(t)$ for all $x \in A$ and $\int_a^\infty g(t)dt$ converges, then $\int_a^\infty f(x,t)dt$ converges uniformly on $A$.

I understand that uniform convergence for improper integrals of this type means that assuming $F(x) = \int_a^\infty f(x,t)dt$ exists (converges) for all $x \in A$, and given an $x \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we can find an $M > a$ s.t.

$$ \bigg{|} F(x) - \int_a^d f(x,t)dt \bigg{|} < \epsilon$$

for all $ d\geq M$. I've been able to show that the improper integral $\int_a^\infty f(x,t)dt$ converges absolutely, but I'm not what this says, if anything, about uniform convergence.

Comment: All convergence results for improper integrals (e.g., comparison test) emanate from the Cauchy criterion for convergence -- so it is worthwhile understanding it. Another good reference is Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the improper integral of $g$ is convergent, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C > a$ (independent of $x$) such that for all $c_2 > c_1 > C$ we have

$$\left| \int_{c_1}^{c_2} f(x,t) \, dt \right| \leqslant \int_{c_1}^{c_2} |f(x,t)| \, dt \leqslant \int_{c_1}^{c_2} g(t) \, dt < \epsilon$$

As this inequality holds for all $x \in A$, convergence is uniform by the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence of improper integrals. See Theorem 2 [here](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_IMPROPER_FUNCTIONS.PDF) for a proof of this criterion.

Comment: I think maybe theorem 4 is what I needed? I thought this was just a Cauchy criterion for convergence, not specifically uniform convergence.

Comment: In the answer we first apply the simple Cauchy criterion to the integral of $g$ where we find the $C(\epsilon)$ such that $c_2 > c_1 > C(\epsilon)$ implies $\int_{c_1}^{c_2} g(t) \, dt  = \left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2} g(t) \, dt  \right| < \epsilon$.  Then using the inequalities we see that $f$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence.  So both theorems are needed.

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the theorems for sequences applied to $F_n(x,t) = \int_a^n f(x,t) \, dt$.  Then you just have to generalize for $\int_a^\infty f(x,t) \, dt = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_a^c f(x,t) \, dt$ where $c$ is not an integer.

Comment: Also if you can look at Bartle, 2nd edition, Theorem 32.5 gives a very  straightforward proof of the (simple) Cauchy Criterion for improper integrals.  This generalizes to a Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence easily.