# Proving uniform convergence: is my understanding correct?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to learn about how to prove the uniform convergence of an integral. My understanding is as follows:
We can prove that the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x, t)dx$$
is uniformly convergent if $|f(x, t)|\le g(x)$
and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx<\infty.$$

Is this correct? If not, please let me know where I made a mistake. Thank you very much for your help, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please precise what you mean by "convergence" ? In my knowledge, we use this term in the context of a sequence "converging" toward something. I do not understand what you're talking about.

Comment: Yes -- that is a sufficient condition for uniform convergence of an improper integral, sometimes referred to as the Weierstrass M-test similar to the result for infinite series.  This has been asked on this site before and is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3652050/148510).

Comment: @Falcon: The uniform convergence in question here is that of $\int_0^\infty f(x,t) \, dx = \lim_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c f(x,t) \, dx$ for the parameter $t$ in some set.